# meaning of pun with 'tackle the piano'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-play

The situation : A repaired all music instrument waiting B. And B comes back with a piano.

A: I just finished my repairs... And I was about to tackle the piano, though that might hurt.

B: hahaha I suppose it would!

What's the meaning of this?
Is it some kind of joke?

Answer (score 2):

The pun here is that `tackle the piano` would normally mean `make an attempt to play`, (though in this case - thanks Kate) the obvious meaning is that `A` is about to attempt to repair the piano, but is being used here in the same sense that a football or Rugby player would understand - i.e a physical 'intervention'. Given that a piano is generally fairly large and immovable, it (should be) obvious that `A` would get hurt in the process.

Comment: Or, if A is a repairer, _make a start on the repair_.

Comment: Kate Bunting is right... context matters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a joke based on (two of the) the different meanings of the word "tackle"

1. To take on or attempt to handle a task
2. To seize, take hold of, or grapple with especially with the intention of stopping or subduing, often involving colliding at high speed.

So, in this case, tackling the piano means he's going attempt to repair the piano.  Tackling a piano, in the second sense, would be painful